# How to make \circledR show up when using newtx?

Tags: symbols, newtxmath, newtx

Compile the following code with `latex`+`dvips`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\begin{document}
\circledR \(\circledR\)
\end{document}
```

As a result, we get an empty document (except the page number).  The compilation finishes successfully, only there is a hint in the log file:

> `"Missing character: There is no ò in font ntxsym!"`

How to get `®` in `newtx` in text and in math? Any (quick) bugfix? After all, the changelog of `newtx` says for version 1.515 this:

> `"Corrected definitions of [...] \circledR"`

so, this character should work.

The newtx author has been e-mailed on 2019-07-11, but has not reacted as of 2019-07-17.  If anyone has an e-mail address of him different from [the one mentioned at CTAN](http://web.archive.org/web/20170614225447/http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/newtx), please feel free to nag him.

Crosspost: http://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=48&t=32670

Comment: The definition points to a non existent glyph. You can use `\textregistered`, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, the characters in slots octal 362 and 363 of the font `ntxsym` didn't go through and indeed, if I look at the virtual font I see

```
(CHARACTER O 361
   (CHARWD R 0.504)
   (CHARHT R 0.688499)
   (CHARIC R 0.03)
   (MAP
      (MOVERIGHT R 0.03)
      (SELECTFONT D 1)
      (SETCHAR C q)
      )
   )
(CHARACTER O 364
   (CHARWD R 0.684)
   (CHARHT R 0.729)
   (CHARIC R 0.03)
   (MAP
      (MOVERIGHT R 0.03)
      (SELECTFONT D 1)
      (SETCHAR C t)
      )
   )
```

The two glyphs should be the circled R and S.

You can get them from the TX fonts where they should come from anyway.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}

\renewcommand{\circledR}{\mbox{\usefont{U}{txsya}{m}{n}\symbol{'162}}}
\renewcommand{\circledS}{\mbox{\usefont{U}{txsya}{m}{n}\symbol{'163}}}

\begin{document}

\circledR\ \circledS

\end{document}
```

[image]

### UPDATE 2020

The fonts have been fixed. Now

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}

\begin{document}

\circledR \(\circledR\)

\(\circledS\)

\end{document}
```

will give the expected result. Note that `\circledS` is defined as a math symbol, so it cannot be used in text mode.

Comment: @MdAyq5 I proposed a workaround. Anyway, `\textregistered` seems even better.

Comment: @user49915 The fonts have been fixed; the package author decided that `\circledS` is only a math symbol.